# How do I append a node to my XML via Java

Tags: java, xml

Trying to make it so when they hit the exit button, their name and money amount is stored in an XML file. I have it also to read the current XML file there

Having trouble adding a new node to the XML File.

```
private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("scores.xml");

        Element rootElement = document.createElement("scores");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        Element player = document.createElement("player");
        Element playerName = document.createElement("name");
        Element moneyAmount = document.createElement("money");
        playerName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        playerName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(String.valueOf(money)));
        player.appendChild(playerName);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult("scores.xml");
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.exit(0);
        }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Current XML:

```
<scores>
    <player>
        <name>Chief Sosa</name>
        <money>1000</money>
    </player> 
</scores>
```

I want to add another player 
Desired:

```
<scores>
    <player>
        <name>Chief Sosa</name>
        <money>1000</money>
    </player> 

    <player>
        <name>Kobe</name>
        <money>11000000</money>
    </player> 
</scores>
```

Comment: This problem seems to have nothing to do with Swing (note: 'The GUI is written using Swing' does not count).  Apply tags more carefully in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes an pre-existing scores file...

Start by getting the document's "root" node...

```
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
```

Then rather than trying to append the "text" from the variables `name` and `money`...

```
// This is creating a mess
Element player = document.createElement("player");
Element playerName = document.createElement("name");
Element moneyAmount = document.createElement("money");
playerName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
playerName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(String.valueOf(money)));
player.appendChild(playerName);
```

You want to set the appropriate nodes text content

```
Element player = document.createElement("player");
Element playerName = document.createElement("name");
playerName.setTextContent(name);
Element moneyAmount = document.createElement("money");
moneyAmount.setTextContent(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(money));
```

Next, you want to append the name and moneny nodes to the `player` element...

```
player.appendChild(playerName);
player.appendChild(moneyAmount);
```

Then append the `player` node to the "root"

```
rootElement.appendChild(player);
```

**Updated**

You could use the following...

```
Document document = null;
File scores = new File("scores.xml");
if (scores.exists()) {

    document = documentBuilder.parse("scores.xml");

} else {

    document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    document.appendChild(document.createElement("scores"));

}
```

To either load or create a new document if it didn't exist, then use the appending code as per the previous example...

**Updated with example...**

Using...

```
try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = null;
    File scores = new File("scores.xml");
    if (scores.exists()) {

        document = documentBuilder.parse("scores.xml");

    } else {

        document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        document.appendChild(document.createElement("scores"));

    }

    Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();

    String name = "Kobe";
    double money = 11000000;

    Element player = document.createElement("player");
    Element playerName = document.createElement("name");
    playerName.setTextContent(name);
    Element moneyAmount = document.createElement("money");
    moneyAmount.setTextContent(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(money));

    player.appendChild(playerName);
    player.appendChild(moneyAmount);

    rootElement.appendChild(player);

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(scores);
    tf.transform(source, result);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | TransformerException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And starting with...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<scores>
    <player>
        <name>Chief Sosa</name>
        <money>1,000</money>
    </player>
</scores>
```

I was able to generate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<scores>
    <player>
        <name>Chief Sosa</name>
        <money>1,000</money>
    </player>
    <player>
        <name>Kobe</name>
        <money>11,000,000</money>
    </player>
</scores>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question? Do I even need the transformer part if I am using your way? I get a problem, I have to throw or declare the transformer exception

Comment: Yes, you still need to export the XML at the end of it.  Any manipulations you're doing are done purely in memory on the model, not the source of the document

Comment: Ahh yes, okay I missed a exception. but uh when I exit and it transfers over the new results. It ends up placing 2 root elements.

i.e <scores>Stuff!</scores> <scores>Stuff2</scores>

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean, I've posted the code I tested with

Comment: Must've entered something wrong in. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 possible solutions for you:

**1.** Define your node id  by setAttribute function. After that the xml file will look like below

> ```
> <scores id ="scoreId">
>
> </scores>
> ```

When you want to add another player. Find an node with ID by using:

```
Node n = document.getElementById("scoreId");
```

Create an Player
And finally apendChild in this node.

**2 .** Another solution is using `document.getElementsByTagName("scores");`

Loop in this result and append your node.

Hope this help